# What is the meaning of practiced upon here?

Tags: meaning

> Sammy has been **practised upon**, and has broken confidence. It has all come out. You had better not be in the way, for strangers are going to call upon you. They have been very quiet as yet, because they mean to surprise you. Don't lose time. I didn't. I am not to be found anywhere. If I was you, I wouldn't either. S. B., late of B. M.

Answer (score 2):

The passage is from Dickens's "The Old Curiosity Shop".
Sammy has broken confidence, that is, has given away a secret.

The meaning of *practised upon* may be this one:
Merriam-Webster *practice*
(intransitive verb)
5: **to take advantage of someone**
example:
*he practised on their credulity with huge success*
The Times Literary Supplement (London)

So, someone has taken advantage of Sammy to make him give up a secret.

[Project Gutenberg *text of the work*](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/700/pg700.txt)